# Android SDL2 App black screen then exits

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, logcat, sdl-2

I have a working SDL2 demo running in Windows, but when I port this code to Android the finished app will display a black screen for few seconds and then quietly exit (no errors, nothing), rather than display the pretty test graphics within a game-loop.

If I add a call to `SDL_ShowSimpleMessageBox` at the start of my main, nothing happens (I've since learned that it's not implemented for Android yet - grrr), but if I comment-out my main code, ndk-build complains that it's missing, so it's certainly being included in the build, but doesn't appear to get called.

I've followed the steps in `README-android.txt`. After about 200 hours of solving problems over the past 2 months I eventually produced an apk. Have the following fixes I made maybe broken something?

The first problem is NDK-BUILD failing to find `SDL_config.h`, because of the instructions at step #2 in `README-android.txt` being wrong. Fixed restructuring the directories, or editing paths in `Android.mk`.

Second problem is NDK-BUILD failing to find `EGL/eglplatform.h`. Fixed by adding `APP_PLATFORM := android-9` to `Application.mk`.

Third problem is NDK-BUILD not recognising C++11, so I added `APP_CPPFLAGS += -std=c++11` to `Application.mk`.

Fourth problem is NDK-BUILD not finding `#include <cstdarg>` (used for `va_list` and `va_start`). Including `<SDL.h>` instead fixed this.

Fith problem is `ant` build `failing at [aapt] Generating resource IDs`. I fixed this in Android SDK Manager by deleting build-tools verion 21.1.1 and installing version 20 instead.

This is the first time I've posted for help on here because I'm desperate. I'm a veteran C++ coder but a complete novice when it comes to java. I'm using C++ in eclipse for the Windows SDL2, and I built the apk entirely from the command-line.

Tried on several different devices. Looking at the logcat, there's a `signal 7 SIGBUS` error:

```
V/SurfaceView( 3497): Layout: x=0 y=0 w=1280 h=720, frame=Rect(0, 0 - 1280, 720)
F/libc    ( 3497): Fatal signal 7 (SIGBUS) at 0x00000000 (code=128)
I/ActivityManager(  162): Displayed org.libsdl.app/.SDLActivity: +416ms
V/SDL     ( 3497): onWindowFocusChanged(): true
W/InputManagerService(  162): Starting input on non-focused client
com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$StubProxy@410b72d8 (uid=10021 pid=331)
```

Comment: I replaced my SDL2 source code with a simple main.c which displays a box and pauses - it works! The Android build is working, so there's something wrong with my code which works on Windows, but not Android. I've been strict about keeping my code portable. At least now I know where the fault is, I can isolate parts of my code until it works. Watch this space...

Comment: It's worth noting that SDL2's `SDL_ShowSimpleMessageBox` doesn't do anything on the Android implementation. Very frustrating as I was relying on this to debug.

Comment: Coming back to SDL's Android build after over 3 years and the SDL dev team have done a lot of work since then and it all works nicely under the new Android Studio 3. None of these issues are relevant now.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the problem. Feel free to slap my wrists.

I've always coded with the assumption that I can address memory with 8-bit aligned pointers. This has worked for me for the past 25 years, until now. My code fails when it's targeting Android because whatever CPU it's using refuses to address memory with pointers that are 8-bit aligned. So as soon as I move a pointer along a byte-aligned butter and cast that pointer to an object and reference that pointer, BAM, android quietly exits the app.

Now the question is what to do with this question? It logs all the problems and solutions I've battled with over the past 2 months, so must be useful to someone?

Comment: YES! I'm going through the same shit as you right now, albeit a bit faster. I actually hoped my program would run on the first try after I finished downloading gigabytes of SDK files and solving a plethora of build bugs. Well I hope I have the same alignment problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but quite a different cause.
After starting the app it remained black and seemed to minimize itself after half a second. Switching to the app also minimized it again.

It turns out Makefile Syntax highlighting is bugged in SciTE (and also Stackoverflow it seems), so that something like this:

```
# LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(SDL_PATH)/src/main/android/SDL_android_main.c \
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(SDL_PATH)/src/main/android/SDL_android_main.c \
    $(PROJECT_PATH)/main.cpp
```

was in effect commented out completely but not shown as such. This resulted in I guess the main routine from SDL being used instead of mine.

This problem could be spotted by looking into the compiled file with `nm -C android-project/obj/local/arm64-v8a/libmain.so` and noticing that it contains almost no functions:

```
00000000000004c4 t atexit
00000000000004ac t __atexit_handler_wrapper
0000000000011008 A __bss_end__
0000000000011008 A _bss_end__
0000000000011008 A __bss_start
0000000000011008 A __bss_start__
                 U __cxa_atexit@@LIBC
                 U __cxa_finalize@@LIBC
0000000000010d70 t $d
0000000000011000 d $d
0000000000011000 d __dso_handle
0000000000010d80 a _DYNAMIC
0000000000011008 A _edata
0000000000011008 A _end
0000000000011008 A __end__
0000000000010ff8 a _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
00000000000004a0 t __on_dlclose
00000000000004ac t $x
00000000000004a0 t $x
0000000000000480 t $x
```